# How to reduce the output of the Curl command?

Tags: linux, curl

Am looking for a way to restrict the output of curl command

For example when using curl to check if port is open on server, just want to restrict the output to first lines to confirm that port is open

curl -v host:1521
want to just display first 3 lines of output
*About to connect to
*Trying host ..connected
* Connected to host

Answer (score 0):

Why not to pipe it to `head`?

```
curl -v host:1521 | head -n3
```

where `-n3` means 3 lines from top.

EDIT:

As discussed in comments you use `-v` option to capture headers etc. which are printed on stderr instead of stdout so `head` doesn't affect it. You have to redirect stderr to stdout and after that operate on:

```
curl -v www.example.com 2>&1 | grep Connected
```

This will return `* Connected to www.example.com (IP_ADDRESS_HERE) port 443 (#0)` if connected successfully and nothing otherwise.

Comment: thanks i tried that but still seeing all the output

Comment: for example if i curl host:1521 i just want * Connected to host (10.1.1.1) port 1521 (#0) i  tried to use the -n flag curl -v -n host:1521 | head 3 but no dice

Comment: Your service probably returns all information in the single line. Because of that `-n3` doesn't work. If you limit output to 3 lines but have one it will print all anyways. Please post entire output then I can help more.

Comment: If we take example curl -v www.rte.ie:443 | head -n3 The only info I want to know is * Connected to www.rte.ie (104.18.163.29) port 443 (#0), but I get everything. The reason I need this I need to check this on about 50 servers where nc / telnet is not installed I only have curl to work with

Comment: I found on another forum -N switch for curl will ignore the buffer, so like you said that will return the top 3 but only of the header, seems to ignore * connected

Comment: OK, you haven't provided that you use `-v` option. First part returned in this case is sent to stderr co head is not going to affect this. You have to redirect stderr to stdout and after that make operations on it. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: Try `curl -i  host:1521 2>/dev/null | less` to see what is received, then see what you need from that.